# Proof by cases: if $n$ is a positive integer and $\sqrt{n}$ isn't an integer, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

There are multiple posts about this proof already ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120928/prove-that-the-square-root-of-a-positive-integer-is-either-an-integer-or-irratio)), but none of them attempt to prove the statement using cases (from my knowledge). I'm not sure if this method is possible as I can't seem to prove the last case.

My (rough) work is below:

**Proof by contradiction:**

Assume that $\sqrt{n}$ is rational. Let $\sqrt{n} = \frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in Z^+, b\neq0$ be a ratio of integers in their most reduced form. We know that both $a$ and $b$ cannot both be even, as that would simplify the fraction further.

It follows that $n=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$, therefore $a^2=nb^2$,

**Case 1: $a$ even, $b$ odd**

Let $a=2c$. It follows that $(2c)^2=4c^2=nb^2$, which leads to a contradiction that $b$ is even.

**Case 2: $a$ odd, $b$ even**

Let $b=2d$. It follows that $a^2=n(2d)^2=4nd^2$, which leads to a contradiction that $a$ is even.

**Case 3: $a$ odd, $b$ odd**

I have tried approaching this in three ways:

Method 1: Let $a=2x+1$. It follows that $(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1=nb^2$.

Method 1: Let $b=2y+1$. It follows that $a^2=n(2y+1)^2 =n(4y^2+4y+1)$.

Method 3: Let $a=2x+1, b=2y+1$. It follows that $(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1=n(2y+1)^2 =n(4y^2+4y+1)$.

I can't find a contradiction in any of these statements. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this started as a proof for the case $n=2$.

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo. I meant $a^2=nb^2$.

Comment: Case 1 is wrong.

Comment: More specifically, if $n$ is even your argument is not always true for case 1.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has a downvote. The OP has shown his attempts. This discourages the OP.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I think I know how to approach this correctly now.

Comment: Completely agree with @Ramanujan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The even/odd thing for the case $n=2$ is specific to $2$.  For the general case,  you want to consider a prime $p$ such that occurs to an odd power in the prime factorization of $n$ (and thus this will depend on the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic).  You then consider the highest powers of $p$ that divide $a$ and $b$.