# Is this irrationality proof valid?

Tags: solution-verification

We aim to prove that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational. Consider the polynomial
$p(x) = x^2 - 6$
Note that
$p(\sqrt{6}) = (\sqrt{6})^2 - 6 = 0, $
hence $\sqrt{6}$ is a root of $p(x)$.

Now, consider the Rational Root Theorem, which states that any rational root of the polynomial equation $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 = 0$, with integer coefficients, must be of the form $ \frac{p}{q}$, where (p) is a factor of the constant term $a_0$ and $q$ is a factor of the leading coefficient $a_n$.

For our polynomial $p(x) = x^2 - 6$, the set of all possible rational roots is 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 6, -6. However, $\sqrt{6}$ is not included in this set. Since $\sqrt{6}$ is a root of the equation but is not in the set of possible rational roots, it must not be rational.

Therefore, we conclude that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational.

Comment: This is correct. In fact using exactly the same machinery shows that for every natural number $n$, either $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer or irrational

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the square root of a positive integer is either an integer or irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120928/prove-that-the-square-root-of-a-positive-integer-is-either-an-integer-or-irratio). There it is criticised to use the Rational Root Theorem without a proof.